# Defaulting a column to the 1st of next month

Tags: sql-server-2012, default-value

I'm trying to find the most elegant means of defaulting a column's value to the 1st of next month. The best I've been able to come up with is this:

```
ALTER TABLE Foo ADD
Bar datetimeoffset(0) NOT NULL DEFAULT(DATEFROMPARTS(DATEPART(year, DATEADD(month, 1, GETDATE())), DATEPART(month, DATEADD(month, 1, GETDATE())), 1))
```

Whilst this works, it feels really clunky because I need to calculate `DATEADD(month, 1, GETDATE())` twice *and* because I need to do the `DATEFROMPARTS` dance.

Is there a simpler way to achieve my goal?

Comment: FinalDate = CURRENT_DATE - DAY(CURRENT_DATE) + 1 DAY + 1 MONTH

Comment: @Akina Sure, but when you convert that to a compilable expression it _still_ ends up very unwieldy...

Comment: What's the point of saving bytes of query text? Well, use `DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE())+(MONTH(GETDATE())/12), 1+(MONTH(GETDATE())%12), 1)`

Comment: The point is readability/not wasting developer time, not "saving bytes"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It think this would be the simplest way to do it.

`DATEADD(DD,1,EOMONTH (GETDATE()))`

So you query would be like

```
ALTER TABLE Foo ADD
Bar datetimeoffset(0) NOT NULL DATEADD(DD,1,EOMONTH (GETDATE()));
```

Thanks!

Comment: Interesting - thanks! I'll try this out ASAP.